# csscomb remove linebreak between soorting groups

Tags: css, node.js, sass, csscomb

Im using csscomb.js to organize my css. 
It works perfectly except I don't want the linebreaks in between the soorting groups.[see image]

Is there a way to remove those?
I looked every where.

[image]**example**

This is mij setup:

```
 "remove-empty-rulesets": false,
    "always-semicolon": true,
    "color-case": "lower",
    "block-indent": "  ",
    "color-shorthand": false,
    "element-case": "lower",
    "leading-zero": true,
    "quotes": "single",
    "sort-order-fallback": "abc",
    "space-before-colon": "",
    "space-after-colon": " ",
    "space-before-combinator": " ",
    "space-after-combinator": " ",
    "space-between-declarations": "\n",
    "space-before-opening-brace": " ",
    "space-after-opening-brace": "\n",
    "space-after-selector-delimiter": "\n",
    "space-before-selector-delimiter": "",
    "space-before-closing-brace": "\n",
    "strip-spaces": false,
    "tab-size": true,
    "unitless-zero": true,
    "vendor-prefix-align": true,
```

Comment: You can see this issue discussed here: https://github.com/csscomb/csscomb.js/issues/314. 
As the creator says: 
You need to define sort-order array with all properties being in one group.
For example: `"sort-order": {["display", "vertical-align", "color"]}` instead of `"sort-order": {[["display"], ["vertical-align"], ["color"]]}`.
There is no other way to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option for that, but here is a workaround that I use.

Edit property named **sort-order** like this:

### Original:

```
"sort-order": [
        [
            "font",
            "font-family",
            "font-size",
            "font-weight",
            "font-style",
            "font-variant",
            "font-size-adjust",
            "font-stretch",
            "font-effect",
            "font-emphasize",
            "font-emphasize-position",
            "font-emphasize-style",
            "font-smooth",
            "line-height"
        ],
        [
            "position",
            "z-index",
            "top",
            "right",
            "bottom",
            "left"
        ],
        ...
```

### New:

```
    "sort-order": [
        [
            "font",
            "font-family",
            "font-size",
            "font-weight",
            "font-style",
            "font-variant",
            "font-size-adjust",
            "font-stretch",
            "font-effect",
            "font-emphasize",
            "font-emphasize-position",
            "font-emphasize-style",
            "font-smooth",
            "line-height",
            "position",
            "z-index",
            "top",
            "right",
            "bottom",
            "left",
            ...
         ]
     ]
```

Basically you merge the groups into one, so no separating lines are added.
Here is official response from Csscomb creators: [github.com/csscomb/csscomb.js/issues/314](https://github.com/csscomb/csscomb.js/issues/314)

Answer (score -1):

You can try to connect the plug [csscomb-group-size](https://github.com/tonyganch/csscomb-group-size) to csscomb, as is looking for the answer itself ....
[Here a](https://habrahabr.ru/post/230589/) little bit about that developers write:

> CSScomb - a great tool, but sometimes you want to add anything. So we
>   tried to make the code as much as possible a modular and easily
>   expandable. You can add the "comb" the desired function is not
>   bothered with the fork. To do this, there are three ways:
>
> ```
> connect a third-party plug-in
> write your plugin
> done on the basis of its postprocessor CSScomb
> ```
>
> Third-party plug-ins
>
> The easiest way to use someone else's plug. For example, here's an
>   option that removes the blank line between the declarations groups
>   when the group returns too little. Connect plugin is quite simple, for
>   this is the `use ()` method:

```
var CSScomb = require('csscomb');
var groupSize = require('csscomb-group-size');

 // Number 4 indicates that if the group is less than 4 returns between this
 // And the previous group will remove the empty string delimiter:
var config = { 'group-size': 4 };

// Create a new instance of the "comb":
var csscomb = new CSScomb().use(groupSize).configure(config);

// Works wonders:
csscomb.processPath('path/to/css');
```

But how to make it all work, I could not understand, perhaps, you will learn in detail the documentation and understand.